# Superposition and Thinning of Poisson Processes

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

Given two arrival processes $N_t = X_t + Y_t$, $X_t$ and $Y_t$ independent, with $Y_t$,$X_t$ each occuring with $P = 0.5$, what is $E[N_t|X_t = n]$?

To answer this, I'm trying to find  find $P(N_t|N_s=n)$, given $t,s \geq 0$, $N\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

$$\frac{P(N_t = M)P(N_t-N_s = n - m)}{P(N_s=n)}$$

$$\frac{e^{-t}(t)^n}{m!} \frac{e^{-\lambda (s-t)}\lambda (s-t)^{m-n}}{(n-m)!}$$

which reduces to

$$ \binom{n}{m}(\frac{t}{s})^m (1-\frac{t}{s})^{n-m}$$

which is clearly a binomial.

However, I think I might have approached this problem from the wrong direction (I fail to see how the above is useful for solving this problem), and I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: $X_t\mid N_t$ has a conditionally binomial distribution, but $N_t\mid X_t$ is rather different.  Which are you trying to find?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yeah, I was thinking that too, which is why I'm confused. I'm not even sure if the two are even remotely related. The expectation I was looking for in that part of my answer isn't related to $X_t$ - it's something along the lines of $E[N_2 = 1 | N_4 = 3]$. I know that $N_t$ is a superposition of $X_t$ and $Y_t$, and that each separate process occurs with probability $0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the Linearity of Expectation.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(N_t\mid X_t) & = \mathsf E(X_t+Y_t\mid X_t) \\[1ex] & = \mathsf E(X_t\mid X_t)+\mathsf E(Y_t\mid X_t) \\[1ex] & = \ldots\end{align}$$

Which, if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent, then simplifies into an easy solution.   Are they?

Comment: Does this results hold for a general renewal process? see the problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825150/thinning-a-renewal-process-poisson-generalization

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah, I was thinking that too, which is why I'm confused. I'm not even sure if the two are even remotely related. The expectation I was looking for in that part of my answer isn't related to $X_t$ - it's something along the lines of $E[N_2 =1\mid N_4 =3]$. I know that $N_t$ is a superposition of $X_t$ and $Y_t$, and that each separate process occurs with <s>probability</s><sup>rate</sup> $0.5$ .

If $X_t \perp Y_t,\textsf{ and } X_t, Y_t \mathop{\sim}^\textsf{iid} \mathcal P(0.5t)$ , then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(N_t=k) & = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(0.5t)^{j} e^{-0.5t}}{j!}\frac{(0.5t)^{k-j} e^{-0.5t}}{(k-j)!} \\[1ex] & = (0.5t)^k e^{-t}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{j!(k-j)!} \\[1ex] & = (0.5t)^k e^{-t} 2^k \frac 1 {k!} \\ & =\dfrac{t^k e^{-t}}{k!}\end{align}$$

Which is to say, $N_t\sim \mathcal{Pois}(t)$ (as expected: the sum of the counts of two i.i.d. poison processes with rate $\lambda$ is the count of a poison process with rate $2\lambda$.)

---

So are you looking for $$\mathsf E(\{N_2=1\} \mid \{N_4=3\}) = \dfrac{ \mathsf P(N_2=1)\cdot\mathsf P(N_4-N_2=2) }{ \mathsf P(N_4=3) }$$

Or $$\mathsf E(N_2\mid N_4=4) = \sum_{n=0}^{3} \dfrac{ n\;\mathsf P(N_2=n)\cdot\mathsf P(N_4-N_2=3-n) }{ \mathsf P(N_4=3) }$$

Comment: No, I actually did mean probability - it's a superposition of two different Poisson Processes - $N_2$ and $N_4$ were just given as examples for illustration. By thinning of Poisson Processes, we can say that $X_t \sim \text{Poisson}$($p\lambda_1$) and $Y_t \sim \text{Poisson}$($(1-p)\lambda_2)$.

Comment: Does this results hold for a general renewal process? see the problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825150/thinning-a-renewal-process-poisson-generalization